# Using how to import data set into excel and return as memorystream? receiving an error inside workbook.Save(stream)

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

[image]

```
public static MemoryStream GenerateExcelReport(DataSet objDS)
    {

        // Instantiating a Workbook object            
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

        // Obtaining the reference of the worksheet
        Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        // Instantiating a "Products" DataTable object
        DataTable dataTable = objDS.Tables[0];


        // Importing the contents of DataTable to the worksheet starting from "A1" cell,
        // Where true specifies that the column names of the DataTable would be added to
        // The worksheet as a header row
      
        worksheet.Cells.ImportDataTable(dataTable, true, "A1");
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        // Saving the Excel file
        workbook.Save(stream);


        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the actual image that you are seeing?

Comment: Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/different-ways-to-save-files/#:~:text=%E2%9D%A4%20by%20GitHub-,Saving%20File%20to%20a%20Stream,when%20calling%20the%20Save%20method.) It looks like you are missing a parameter

Answer (score 0):

`Workbook` has two [Save](https://apireference.aspose.com/cells/net/aspose.cells/workbook/save/) methods that accept `Stream`.

`public void Save(Stream stream, SaveFormat saveFormat)` where `SaveFormat` represents the format in which the workbook is saved.

`public void Save(Stream stream, SaveOptions saveOptions)` where `SaveOptions` represents all save options.

You need to specify the second argument either `SaveFormat` or `SaveOptions`.

Try to call `Save` with one of possible `SaveFormat` value like `Xlsx`.

Example:

```
// Saving the Excel file
workbook.Save(stream, SaveFormat.Xlsx);
```